# Cron Daemon Wget blocked

Tags: nginx, cron, debian-wheezy, wget, http-status-code-403

I've got **nginx** on **Debian 7** without cpanel.

I am seting-up my Crontab like this:

```
*/45 * * * * wget "http://example.com/cron-url.php" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The above cron is being blocked with 403 forbidden:

```
--2014-12-10 05:40:01--  http://example.com/cron-url.php
Connecting to xyz.xx.xx.xxx:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-12-10 05:40:01 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

After searching here and googling, I understand that my server is probably blocking wget. I had a look at my nginx configuration file and I think it should be due to this:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* LWP::Simple|BBBike|wget) {
    return 403;
}
```

For cron command, I have to use the url to it and absolute link to script path doesn't work. Now, what do I do if I need to allow cron to work without getting blocked? I was thinking maybe I need to allow wget from my own server, but don't know how to do that with nginx. Can someone help me resolve this cron issue?

Comment: ...remove `wget` from the nginx configuration?

Comment: true.. but that will also allow others to use wget to download contents from my site, isint it?

Comment: Now, I noticed that I can access the cron url from browser though.

Comment: Hyppy's answer should work. Blocking the user-agent doesn't do a whole lot anyway because those are easily spoofed.

Comment: makes sense. I now agree that removing wget is probably the way to go. Thank you NathanC and Hyppy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either remove `wget` exclusion from the nginx configuration, or add something like this as an option to your `wget` command:

```
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101  Firefox/21.0" --referrer whatever.example.com
```

Comment: right... @NathanC was suggesting to remove `wget` from config too. But isint that a security risk? Can someone download sensitive files from my site using wget?

Comment: @blackops_programmer `wget` is only as powerful as someone using a browser ...they can't download "sensitive" stuff if it's otherwise hidden (because then they could just use a regular browser!)

Comment: Even if they were crawling your site with a script full of wgets, they could just modify the user agent and referrer to get the same result. I have no idea why nginx denies wget by default, perhaps it's some sort of greybeard pissing contest.

Comment: Perfect. I misunderstood how wget is used. Now everything makes sense. I dont see the point to add a special block for wget anymore.. :)